# using include with a word from database

Tags: php, database, include

Im having a little problem and cant get it to resolved for some reason. I have built a website  and got it running but i have now passed some of the files over to a folder to build more themes. What i am doing is trying to change themes back end and for this instance i will use the theme "smooth"

this is what i have, if i put this:

```
<?php
include "config_inc.php";
?>
include "themes/<?=$aset['Theme']?>/index.php]";
```

it will display on the page as the correct path "themes/smooth/index.php" so i know it is connecting to the database correctly. But now if i put it in this format:

```
<?php
include "config_inc.php";
?>
<?php
include "themes/<?=$aset['Theme']?>/index.php]";
?>
```

It just shows a blank page.
I have tested the link as in "my_domain/themes/smooth/index.php" and every is displaying correctly

Hope someone can help. Thanks

Comment: @Notulysses include "themes/{$aset['Theme'}/index.php]"; This did not work either

Comment: @Notulysses dosent work either. Is there a spare [ ?

Comment: @Notulysses Got it to work. You missed the end ] after Theme']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use php tags inside php tags to insert variable in string. Just use `{}` to do it:

```
include "themes/{$aset['Theme']}/index.php";
```

Or

```
include 'themes/' . $aset['Theme'] . '/index.php';
```